# Android (Java), variable default reference type?

Tags: java, android

Today i try to learn android sdk, but experience a very strange problem.

Below is the code of :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_complete_test);

    Cursor cur = getBrowserData(); //Return an amount of data in cursor type.
    UrlAdapter adapter = new UrlAdapter(AutoCompleteTest.this, cur);
    //cur.close(); uncomment this, data will gone.

    AutoCompleteTextView txtUrl = (AutoCompleteTextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
    txtUrl.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The problem is on the line : **cur.close();**
UrlAdapter is custom class to fill the **Cursor** to **adapter**, and bind to AutoCompleteTextView.

On above, after i fill the cur (Cursor) to adapter, i close the cur for resource saving.
However, after i close the cur, it affect the adapter.

The `AutoComplete` list will be nothing.

But it don't happen on `C#`,
Just like i fill `DataTable` to `DataAdaptor`, and `Dispose()` the `DataTable`, the dataon DataAdaptor will be preserve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the `Cursor` by reference, so there's a single instance of `Cursor` both in `Adapter` and in `Activity`. So once you closed the `Cursor` in `Activity`, you can't continue using it in the `Adapter`. So close it only when you're sure you don't need it again. Another problem with your code is that making database calls on the main thread is prohibited, try to rewrite your code using `AsyncTask` or `Loader`.

Comment: Thanks, is it any keyword i can set the scope of "cur", so that i close the cur in activity, but not affect adaptor. thanks you.

Comment: @Shiba, No, there's no such solution in Java.

Answer (score 1):

What Egor says is absolutely right. Also you  need to optimize your code little more like below:

```
try {
        Cursor cur = getBrowserData(); //Return an amount of data in cursor type.
        UrlAdapter adapter = new UrlAdapter(AutoCompleteTest.this, cur);
        
    
        AutoCompleteTextView txtUrl = (AutoCompleteTextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        txtUrl.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch(Exception ex) { 
        // Log the exception's message or whatever you like
Log.e("Exception", ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
          if( cur != null && !cursor.isClosed )
            cur .close();
           
        } catch(Exception ex) {Log.e("Exception", ex.getMessage());}
    }
```